# How to get inner <div> id from string

Tags: jquery

I know its a common issue but still having issue so need good suggestion or fix of it.

My Issue is

```
text = "<div class='catDiv'><div id='1689' class='cat'>Baby</div></div>";
```

Now I need inner div id from above string via jQuery.

```
catid = $(text).filter("div");
ct = $(catid).filter("div").attr("id");
```

I use this but can't get the id

Comment: `catid = $(text).find('div').attr('id')`

Comment: @connexo I use this before not working but its working :/ so strange but it fixed my issue thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just find the `div` from the `text` variable so that it will return you the inner div then get the `id`:

```js
var text = "<div class='catDiv'><div id='1689' class='cat'>Baby</div></div>";
var ct =  $(text).find('div').attr('id')
console.log(ct);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The "magic" is the `$(text)` part which converts the content of `text` into actual DOM elements.

Comment: It converts it to jQuery objects, allowing to access the "actual DOM object" using `$(text)[0]`.